# Java Removing Object from Scene

Tags: java, object

I stumbled upon this problem. In my engine I finally figured out how I add objects to the scene after a condition is met. However I still can't figure out how an object can be removed from the scene.

This is the game loop

```
while(isRunning == true)
    {   
        if(frames > 200)
        {
            building1 = false;
        }

        if(building1 == true) {
            if(frames > 100) {
                if(create_001 == true) {
                    model = true;

                    loadModel();

                    create_001 = false;
                }
            }
        }
[...]
```

the (create_001 = false;) is there so that the object is only created once.

And this is how the models are being loaded in:

```
private Game game;

public void loadModel() {
    GameObject object = new GameObject();
    Mesh mesh = new Mesh(obj);
    Material material = new Material (new Texture(texture));
    MeshRenderer meshRenderer = new MeshRenderer(mesh, material);
    object.AddComponent(meshRenderer);
    game.AddObject(object);
}
```

As you can see I make the object appear after 100 frames and try to remove the object again after 200 frames by disabeling the building1 if check - however this doesn't work.

After 200 frames the object is still there and I wouldn't know why, has anyone a suggestion because I can't understand why it wouldn't work like that?

Thanks for any Help!

EDIT:

Here's the game class where I have the AddObject method which I call at the end of loadModel method:

```
public abstract class Game
{
private GameObject m_root;

public void Init() {}
public void Input(float delta) { GetRootObject().InputAll(delta); }
public void Update(float delta) { GetRootObject().UpdateAll(delta); }
public void Render(RenderingEngine renderingEngine) { renderingEngine.Render(GetRootObject()); }
public void AddObject(GameObject object) { GetRootObject().AddChild(object); }

private GameObject GetRootObject()
{
    if(m_root == null)
        m_root = new GameObject();

    return m_root;
}

public void SetEngine(CoreEngine engine) { GetRootObject().SetEngine(engine); }
}
```

I probably would need some remove Object method but do not really know how I would need to design it.. I'll try out a little more, but I'm still open for suggestions.

Again thanks for any help!

EDIT2;

Well and here some details about the GameObject class.. it seems we get closer to the root of the problem:

```
private ArrayList<GameObject> m_children;
private CoreEngine m_engine;

public GameObject()
{
    m_children = new ArrayList<GameObject>();
    m_engine = null;
}

public GameObject AddChild(GameObject child)
{
    m_children.add(child);
    child.SetEngine(m_engine);

    return this;
}
```

Thanks for the hints so far, I've tried out several other things but nothing seems to work yet, maybe there can something be done in the GameObject class?

Thanks a lot!

Here's the array list of game objects:

```
public ArrayList<GameObject> GetAllAttached()
{
    ArrayList<GameObject> result = new ArrayList<GameObject>();

    for(GameObject child : m_children)
        result.addAll(child.GetAllAttached());

    result.add(this);
    return result;
}
```

and here the setEngine method:

```
public void SetEngine(CoreEngine engine)
{
    if(this.m_engine != engine)
    {
        this.m_engine = engine;

        for(GameComponent component : m_components)
            component.AddToEngine(engine);

        for(GameObject child : m_children)
            child.SetEngine(engine);
    }
}
```

hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to call  some "remove_object" if(frames > 200) ?
Need more complete code to understand.

```
public abstract class Game {
  public void RemoveObject(GameObject object) {
    GetRootObject().RemoveChild(object); 
  }
}

class GameObject {
  public void RemoveChild(GameObject child) {
    m_children.remove(child);
  }
}
```

Comment: there's not really a remove_object code, I can only say game.AddObject since in the game class there's only such a method.. don't know how I could fix that.. a lot of things aren't designed by me. I've added the game class to my question, maybe that's going to help..? Thanks!

Comment: by the way the create_object method is just a collection of multiple loadModel methods, I've adjusted my question to make it more plausible, sorry for that..

Comment: looks like you need to implement
public void RemoveObject(GameObject object) { GetRootObject().RemoveChild(object); }

Comment: Thanks for the hint! But there's no RemoveChild method in GameObject, I guess we're getting closer to the problem, I've edited my question again including details about the GameObject class, I'll try out on my own but  any suggestions are great, you've helped a lot already, thanks!

Comment: public GameObject RemoveChild(GameObject child)
{
    m_children.remove(child);
    child.SetEngine(null); or some child.ClearEngine();

Comment: Unfortunately setEngine(null) changes nothing.. I was wondering if I could acess the ArrayList of game objects, if I can clear it somehow, it might get rid of the object.. or store all loadModel calls in an ArrayList if that's possible and not even bother with the core mechanics of the engine.. but I might need to open up a new question for this, since the topic would be fairly different and needed some thorough explanation - before that I'll try out a few more things on my own - thanks a lot so far, if you have ony more ideas, please feel free to tell me.

Comment: you need to remove directly from m_children list [m_children.remove(child);], GetAllAttached return COPY of list.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. I'm not really sure what you are suggesting, could you please post and answer with the full code, so I can see where and how I'm supposed to implement your idea? If this works though, that would be awesome!

Comment: ah, now I see.. well I already tried to do exactly that but it didn't work.. I don't know why but I seem not to be able to remove the object again once I told the program to do game.AddObject(object); .. there has to be a way to fix this problem.. thanks for your help, maybe in time I'll find out..